# How to calculate a probability from expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable such that $X = X_{1}+X_{2}+\dots+X_{n}$, where
$$
X_{i} = \begin{cases}
1\quad \text{with probability $p$}\\
0\quad \text{otherwise},
\end{cases},\quad 1\leq i\leq n.
$$

Also, $X_{i}$ and $X_{j}$ $(1\leq i<j\leq n)$ are dependent.

My question is: how to calculate

> $\Pr(X=0)$ $\quad$ or $\quad$ $\Pr(X<1)$

I tried to solve this problem by using Chernoff Bound, Janson's Inequality, application of negatively dependent random variables. But

- If $X_{i}$ and $X_{j}$ $(1\leq i<j\leq n)$ are independent, then I use Chernoff Bound, but they are dependent.
- Unfortunately, $\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n} \Pr(X_{i}=1=X_{j})$ is not $o(E(X))$, so I can't use Janson's Inequality.
- $X_{i}$ and $X_{j}$ $(1\leq i<j\leq n)$ are not negatively dependent.

Can you suggest a way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the dependency? If say $X_2 = 1- X_1$ - you can simply solve. BTW if they are independent $\mathbb{P}(X = 0) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^n(1-p)^n$.

Comment: @dEmigOd $X_{2}\neq 1-X_{1}$. and They are dependent.

Comment: I meant $(1-p)^n$

Answer (score 2):

your answer depends on the exact depends structure (i.e. the underlying Copula) of the $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$.
With no further information, $\Bbb P (X=0)$ cannot be further determined.
To illustrate this, considere these two examples for $n =2$.

1.) if $X_1 = X_2$ then $\Bbb P (X=0) = \Bbb P (X_1=0)  = 1-p$.

2.) if $p = \frac 12$ and $X_1 = 1 - X_2$ then $\Bbb P (X=0)  = 0$.

In general if $F$ is the joint distribution of $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$, i.e.
$$
F(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \Bbb P (X_1 = x_1, \dots, X_n = x_n),
$$
then 
$$
\Bbb P (X=0) = F(0, \dots, 0).
$$

Comment: Why (1) is true?

Comment: if $X_1 = X_2$ then $X = 2X_1$ and hence
$$
\Bbb P(X=0) = \Bbb P (2X_1 = 0) = \Bbb P (X_1 = 0) = 1-p.
$$